# How to continue to the first find result when you're at the last in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

When searching for a string in Sublime Text 3, I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate through the results.  This stops when I get to the last result, even if there are more results higher up in the file.

How can I adjust the settings so that if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when I'm on the last find result in the file, it brings me to the first find result?

I presume there must be some setting to enable this, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question [already has an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/873138/sublime-text-find-next-go-back-to-beggining-of-file-like-chrome-does).

> Make sure that you tick the *Wrap* option in the Find bar.
>
> [image]
>
> Then it'll wrap around even if you keep pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> or
>   <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate the `Wrap` option in the options present to the left of your search box (Highlighted below):

[image]